# No surname in Indian passport and applying for Japan visa.

Tags: visas, japan

I have only single name in my passport. Will it be possible to get Japanese visa without surname in Indian passport?

Comment: For sure, this is not a reason to not get a visa. It might make things complicated, as not everybody understands it right away. Depending on the process, make sure to point this out when you can, so they don't think it's an oversight in the form filling.